# How to store results of a Dynamic Query in a temp table without creating a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are writing a stored procedure responsible for getting a stored procedure name and returning a result containing the stored procedure columns and their data types.
However, we bumped into a problem executing a dynamic query to return the results of stored procedure, but we can't store it in a temp table!

You can see our query below:

```
  DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(100)='spGetOraganizationsList',
  @ParamName VARCHAR(100),@DataType VARCHAR(20),
  @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)='EXEC '+'spGetOraganizationsList '

  SELECT  PARAMETER_NAME,DATA_TYPE 
  INTO #Tmp
  FROM  information_schema.PARAMETERS
  WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME=@ProcName

  DECLARE ParamCursor CURSOR 
  FOR SELECT * FROM #Tmp
  OPEN ParamCursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM ParamCursor
  INTO @ParamName,@DataType

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN
  SET @Query=@Query+@ParamName+'=Null,'
  FETCH NEXT FROM ParamCursor INTO @ParamName,@DataType
  END
  CLOSE ParamCursor
  DEALLOCATE ParamCursor
  DROP TABLE #Tmp
  
  EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

The thing is I can't store the results of it in a temp table,
and `OPENROWSET` does not accept variables.

Comment: What does _can't store result of it into a temp table_ mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: i mean result of EXEC sp_executesql @Query...you cant store result of it into a temp table by 'making in query 'method.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting after script execution.

Comment: Can you edit your question, indicate the line that fails, and the exact error message

Comment: it's not matter of error...basically you can not  store result of  sp_executesql into a temp table without creating it...and we cant create a temp table in this situation because we don't know columns of our procedure..unless you have a solution!

Comment: OK so now you have finally described your issue. Maybe you should try using this instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you are talking about SELECT  PARAMETER_NAME,DATA_TYPE INTO #Tmp... This is OK as I checked. You can insert records into #Temp table without creating it before.  The number of Column also created based on the input.

Comment: i still have a problem with 'dm_exec_describe_first_result_set' because stored procedures in which contain dynamic query or temp table return error...say it has dynamic query i get this error ' contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set'

Comment: Have you tried pre-creating a table that is defined exactly like the output of `sp_describe_first_result_set`?. Here are examples of inserting SP results into a table whether or not you know the schema: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/

Comment: unfortunately OPENROWSET won't do the trick because it also has the same problem that we have in 'sp_describe_first_result_set'...when it comes to temp table and dynamic query these methods won't work because the result set of stored procedure would be unpredictable....thanks for your suggestion

Comment: i think it's a challenging issue that how can we retrieve meta data of stored procedure in which there is dynamic query without hard coding result set ?

Comment: if you are not bound to sql only solution, try to use powershell to execute your procs and examine resultset, instead of attempting to store proc results in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it comes from sql concept that it doesn't trust in result of stored procedures and because of that we cannot select on it or store it in a table by 'making in query table' method. 
Unless you create a table and define it's columns and sql trust to you and you insert result of it into this table for example take below situation

```sql
Create table test (name varchar(10),family varchar(20))


Insert into test
Exec sp-testResult
```

Now if you define wrong column for your table  you will receive query runtime error .actually sql doesn't predict result of sp and leaves it to you to define result of your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly INSERT the results of a stored procedure into a TEMP table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeMe
AS
SELECT convert(int, 1) AS DaData
UNION
SELECT convert(int, 2)
GO

CREATE TABLE #Doodles  (AnInteger int)

INSERT #Doodles EXECUTE PurgeMe

SELECT * FROM #Doodles
```

Questions arise about the SCOPE of TEMP tables, however.  You might find that in your calling routine you will not be able to see a TEMP table created within your routine.

The solution to the SCOPE problem is to do the following:

1. Create a minimal TEMP table (say, with one column)
2. Use ALTER TABLE on the TEMP table within your routine to make its schema match
   your needs (this can be tricky, but it can be done)
3. Put data into the TEMP table
4. return from your routine - the calling routine will now be able to access the temp
   table

If this is of interest I can make a longer post with a stored procedure to do the above.  It was written to facilitate dynamic SQL

Comment: Thank you 'Wayane' for your answer,but there is not matter of temp table scope, actually we want to have name of stored procedure and store result of it into a temp table without creating table,you can look at my query written above,thus your answer is not proper for this situation

Comment: In your initial post you wrote "we can't store it in a temp table", but I don't think you meant "it is impossible".

In your comment to me you wrote "store result of it into a temp table without creating table".  

Of course a table must exist in order to store data into a table, whether you use "SELECT INTO #TempTable", which will create the table, or "INSERT #TempTable SELECT ...", for a table that already exists.

Perhaps you could explain in more detail what you mean by these phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Use global temp table and dynamic `OPENROWSET`

```
  DROP TABLE ##Tmp;
  GO

  DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(100)='spGetOraganizationsList',
  @ParamName VARCHAR(100), @DataType VARCHAR(20),
  -- Mind to specify database and schema of the SP
  @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)=' EXEC [mydb].[dbo].spGetOraganizationsList ';
  SELECT  PARAMETER_NAME,DATA_TYPE 
  INTO #Tmp
  FROM  information_schema.PARAMETERS
  WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME=@ProcName;

  -- Build SP exec

  DECLARE ParamCursor CURSOR 
  FOR SELECT * FROM #Tmp
  OPEN ParamCursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM ParamCursor
  INTO @ParamName,@DataType

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN
     SET @Query=@Query+@ParamName+'=Null,'
     FETCH NEXT FROM ParamCursor INTO @ParamName,@DataType
  END
  CLOSE ParamCursor
  DEALLOCATE ParamCursor
  SET @Query = left(@Query, len(@Query) - 1);

  -- Build ad hoc distributed query which creates ##Tmp from SP exec.

  SET @Query = 'SELECT * INTO ##Tmp FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',''' + @Query + ''')';

  EXEC (@Query);

  -- Created by dynamic sql `##Tmp` is availabe in the current context. 
  SELECT *
  FROM ##Tmp;
```

Don't forget to enable ad hoc distributed queries first.

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**EDIT**

My answer solves only one problem, storing the result of a dynamic proc call in a temp table. And there are more problems.

First, `@p=null` just will not compile if the type of `@p` is user-defined table type. You need kind of `declare @t myType;
exec mySp ...  ,@p=@t ...`.

Next is the 'cannot retrieve matadata for sp because contain dynamic query' error you commented on. Looks like you need an application, SqlClr or standalone, which would be capable to read and parse Datasets returned by procs.

Finally, if an SP contains conditional sql which can return a result set of different schema depending on parameter values, the result of all those efforts is still questionable.

Comment: what about stored procedures containing dynamic query? when you attempt to retrieve meta data for these kind of stored procedures you will receive an error saying 'cannot retrieve matadata for sp because contain dynamic query' you also get the same error when using 'sp_describe_first_result_set'

Comment: thank you for your interest to this topic,but i got a question from you, do you think it's possible to write a stored procedure that accepts name of sp and return column names and their data type? i think it's possible just for stored procedure not contain dynamic query.

Comment: @Abolfazl Yes, restricted to SPs with no dynamic sql and no  result sets selected from temp tables, it should be possible. Excluding  user-defined table types of parameters, the above code does it. And `information_schema.PARAMETERS` view contains also all the info to declare a variable needed for that type of parameter.

Comment: I have already written a sp that returns result of sp by sp name,but i wanted to find a solution for sps with temp table and dynamic query,anyway thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Write select query as you want in the stored procedure. You will get the result without creating temp table.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can use an SqlDataReader or a DataTable to get the results from a stored procedure without knowing the schema beforehand. If you then want to write that data to a temporary table, I think you can do that from C# (though I've never tried to do it).